Direct path to files with common syntax in names in linux directory
I have a directory with around thousand files. I want to run an analysis only those files in that dirctory which has for example"TCGA" in their names ending at .bam. So how to direct the path to only files having TCGA in name ends at .bam. For example one file is as
path<-"/path/to/folder/TCGA12_345.bam"

How to form path with all files

/path/to/folder/TCGA.bam

"I want to run an analysis" – If you could type all the matching pathnames by hand, would you be able to straightforwardly pass all of them to a single invocation of the analyzing tool as plain, separate, final arguments? Or would you need many invocations of the analyzing tool (or of a set of tools), one per pathname? Please [edit] the question and clarify. What have you tried so far?

Are you asking how to search for files, and how to direct the output of that search to a file for later analysis? If so, what Linux or Unix distro? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38516/get-list-of-linux-files-recursively-and-direct-output-to-file, for example.
